# How to download a file from webapp folder using JSF 1.1?

Tags: jsf, download, jsf-1.1

I am using JSF 1.1. On click of a button I need to download a file from `webapp/pdf` directory. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just link to its URL directly. Both the server and the browser will do the necessary magic.

The desired HTML output should look like this:

```
<a href="/yourcontext/pdf/filename.pdf">
    Download PDF
<a>
```

The JSF 1.1 on JSP way to generate this HTML is:

```
<h:outputLink value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdf/filename.pdf">
    <h:outputText value="Download PDF" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Or, when you're using JSF 1.1 on Facelets:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/pdf/filename.pdf">
    Download PDF
</h:outputLink>
```

If necessary, throw in some CSS to make it look like a "button".

Comment: Thanks Balus,                                                                       <h:outputLink value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdf/filename.pdf">
    <h:outputText value="Download PDF" /></h:outputLink>                 this gives 404 error I used like                                                 <h:outputLink value="./#{pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdf/filename.pdf">
    <h:outputText value="Download PDF" />
</h:outputLink> its working but the Download PDF is not visible but its there. How it will work on button click